# How to use material-ui AutoComplete to filter table using select key from list and manually enter value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am trying to create filter similar to AWS Dashboard use where we can select filter key like `instance state` then it renders the key on the input and allow user to enter value and then search for it.

I am trying to create similar functionality using material-ui `Autocomplete` with `multiple`. it shows the list and create chip and add to input as I select option but I don't know how to modify that to get what I wanted it to do.

[AWS Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8naSA.png)

code:

```
        <Autocomplete
            multiple
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
            options={columns}
            filterSelectedOptions
            size={"small"}
            style={{ flexGrow: 2 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    variant={"outlined"}
                    placeholder={"Filter Items"}
                />
            )}
        />
```

Answer (score -1):

**Note** : The Below example is not the complete solution. It will help get started/help you to understand the use of AutoComplete material-ui.

This is a sample example which is similar to your problem.
[Click here](https://abhimeruga.github.io/AutoComplete/)

Material-ui supports developers to customize on top of the component which it provides.
I have encountered similar problem too. Here is how, I was able to solve the problem.

To customize your autocomplete material-ui provides set of props which can we overridden.
[Material-ui Autocomplete API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

Please find code sample [here](https://github.com/abhimeruga/AutoComplete/blob/main/src/Components/AutocompleteComponent.jsx).

In the above example the input value can be altered/set/updated with the *onChange* of *TextField* component.
Similarly on selection of value form the dropdown you can make use of *onChange* of *AutoCompolete* component.

> Q) How to populate the text box along with filter that is selected?
> A) In the above example I am updating the inputValue.

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setFilterValue([...new Set([...filterValue, event.target.name])]);
    } else {
      setFilterValue(filterValue.filter((fv) => fv !== event.target.name));
    }
  };
```

> Q)How to show options after selecting the filter?
> A)In above example I have made use of the filterOptions(Autocomplete prop) which is provided by the Autocomplete.

```
  const filterOptions = (options) => {
    const inputOnFilter =
      inputValue.indexOf(":") > 0
        ? inputValue.slice(inputValue.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, inputValue.length)
        : inputValue;

    if (inputOnFilter)
      return options.filter((option) => option?.includes(inputOnFilter));
    return options;
  };
```

Comment: Please indidcate clearly when linking to your own external material (edited), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion .

Comment: actually the key `instance state` also comes from same dropdown menu so I wanted to do something like click first time to get the column name and them click again to show possible values select from.